# Populate a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a List of "Person" object:

```
public class Person
{
   public Int32 Id { get; set; }
   public String Name { get; set; }
   public Document oDocument  { get; set; }
}
```

And also there is Document class.

```
public class Document
{
   public String Type { get; set; }
   public String Code { get; set; }
}
```

I need to populate a DataGridView with that list showing some just two columns:Name(Person) and DocumentCode (Document)

I used this code, but I dont get what I want.

```
  dgvPersona.DataSource = list;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) object *(to project required fields)* and then bind that to your gridview like:

```
var list = (from p in persons
            select new 
                   {
                   Name = p.Name,
                   DocumentCode = p.Document.Code
                   }).ToList();

dgvPersona.DataSource = list;
```

You may select the `Id` as well and keep it in a hidden column in your gridview , so that later you can use it for record updating etc.

Comment: thanks for the replay. And what if want to modify the column name.

Comment: @Flezcano, since you projected into an anonymous type, you can modify the column name in the select statement as well, or you can simply modify the Grid Column header and assign it a new name at design or runtime *(in your code)* like `grid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Some Name";`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  public class Person
        {
            public Int32 Id { get; set; }
            public String Name { get; set; }
            public Document oDocument { get; set; }
        }
        public class Document
        {
            public String Type { get; set; }
            public String Code { get; set; }
        }

     List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
     dgvPersona.DataSource= list.Select(data => new { data.Name, data.oDocument.Code }).ToList();
```